# Game sometimes doesn't execute a randomly chosen strategy

Tags: c++, random

I'm a beginner at c++ and im doing online tutorials and I'm doing my first challenge. It's a game: the player enters the game configuration and then he has to react on the strategy of his ennemy.

The problem is that sometimes, the game ends without any strategy being displayed.  The `stratergyRoll` doesn't seem to work everytime leading me to believe the problem is with my random number generator.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int AmountOfYourMen(string FactionName1);
int AmountOfEnemyMen(string FactionName2);
int EndStatment(string GeneralName, string FactionName1, string FactionName2, int orgfaction1size, int faction1size, int orgfaction2size, int faction2size);
void BattleSim(int &faction2hp, int &faction1hp, int &faction1attack, int &faction2attack, int &faction1size, int &faction2size, int &orghpfaction1, int &orghpfaction2);

int main()
{
  int faction1;
  int faction2;
  int faction1hp;
  int faction2hp;
  int faction1attack;
  int faction2attack;
  int faction1size;
  int faction2size;
  int orgfaction1size;
  int orgfaction2size;
  int orghpfaction1;
  int orghpfaction2;
  string FactionName1;
  string FactionName2;
  string GeneralName;

  int ArmyMove;

  mt19937 RandomGenerator(time(NULL));
  uniform_int_distribution<int> StratergyRoll(1,4);
  uniform_real_distribution<float> yourmove(0.0,1);
  uniform_real_distribution<float> trapsuccess(0.0,1);

  cout<<"Welcome General What Is Your Name"<<endl;
  cin>>GeneralName;
  cout<<"Welcome General "<< GeneralName <<endl;
  cout<<"choose your faction Rome(1) Spartans(2) Carthage(3) Egypt(4) Greece(5)"<<endl;
  cin>> faction1;
  cout<<"now choose the enemy faction Rome(1) Spartans(2) Carthage(3) Egypt(4) Greece(5)"<<endl;
  cin>> faction2;

  if(faction1 == 1){
    FactionName1 = "Romans";
    faction1hp = 120;
    orghpfaction1 = 100;
    faction1attack = 100;
  }
  else if(faction1 == 2){
    FactionName1 = "Spartans";
    faction1hp = 45;
    orghpfaction1 = 45;
    faction1attack = 100;
  } 
  else if(faction1 == 3){
    FactionName1 = "Carthaginians";
    faction1hp = 80;
    orghpfaction1 = 80;
    faction1attack = 60;
  }
  else if(faction1 == 4){
    FactionName1 = "Egyptions";
    faction1hp = 80;
    orghpfaction1 = 80;
    faction1attack = 70;
  }
  else if(faction1 == 5){
    FactionName1 = "Greeks";
    faction1hp = 80;
    orghpfaction1 = 80;
    faction1attack = 80;
  }

  if(faction2 == 1){
    FactionName2 = "Romans";
    faction2hp = 120;
    orghpfaction2 = 100;
    faction2attack = 100;
  }
  else if(faction2 == 2){
    FactionName2 = "Spartans";
    faction2hp = 45;
    orghpfaction2 = 45;
    faction2attack = 100;
  }
  else if(faction2 == 3){
    FactionName2 = "Carthaginians";
    faction2hp = 80;
    orghpfaction2 = 80;
    faction2attack = 60;
  }
  else if(faction2 == 4){
    FactionName2 = "Egyptions";
    faction2hp = 80;
    orghpfaction2 = 80;
    faction2attack = 70;
  }
  else if(faction2 == 5){
    FactionName2 = "Greeks";
    faction2hp = 80;
    orghpfaction2 = 80;
    faction2attack = 80;
  }

  faction1size = AmountOfYourMen(FactionName1);
  orgfaction1size = faction1size;

  faction2size = AmountOfEnemyMen(FactionName2);
  orgfaction2size = faction2size;

  if(StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator) ==1) {
    cout<<"the "<< FactionName2 << " are charging strait ahead using no apparent stratergy what will you do"<<endl;
    cout<<"(1)charge them head on"<<endl;
    cout<<"(2)attempt to surround them"<<endl;
    cin>> ArmyMove;
    if(ArmyMove ==1){
        cout<<"you charge foward meeting your enemy head on"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
    }
    else if(ArmyMove == 2){
        if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) >=0.4){
            cout<<"you have successufuly surrounded your enemy your men get stat boosts"<<endl;
            faction1hp += 40;
            faction1attack +=40;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        } 
        while(faction1size >= 1 && faction2size >=1);
    }
    else if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) < 0.4){
        cout<<"your attempt at surrounding your enemy have failed your men loose stats"<<endl;
        faction1hp -= 50;
        faction1attack -= 50;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
    }
  } 
  else if(StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator)==2){
    cout<<"the "<< FactionName2 << " your enemy is advancing with their cavelry positoned far out on each side and have their infantry in the middle what will you do"<<endl;
    cout<<"(1) ignore the cavlery and charge their infantry head on"<<endl;
    cout<<"(2)tell your cavelry to meet the enemy cavelry head on and tell your infantry to move foward to engage"<<endl;
    cout<<"(3)hold your ground put spearmen on your flanks and at the back of your army"<<endl;
    cin>> ArmyMove;
    if(ArmyMove ==1){
        cout<<"you charge foward meeting your enemy head on"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
    }
    else if(ArmyMove == 2){
        if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) >=0.5){
            cout<<"your cavelry have defeated the enemy cavelry and are now out flanking your enemy. your men get stat boosts"<<endl;
            faction1hp +=50;
            faction1attack +=50;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
        else if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) < 0.5){
            cout<<"your cavelry was defeated and the enemy cavelry is now out flanking your men. stats lost "<<endl;
            faction1hp -= 60;
            faction1attack -= 60;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
    }
    else if(ArmyMove == 3){
        if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) >= 0.1)
            cout<<"your men hold their ground and their cavelry crashed into your speers getting slaughtered"<<endl;
        cout<<" this was a good plan stopping the flanking and increases your stats"<<endl;
        faction2attack -=50;
        faction2hp -= 50;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
    }
    else if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) <= 0.1){
        cout<<"your men hold and their cavelry crashed into your speers"<<endl;
        cout<<"this seemed like a good plan however the cavelry broke through and you are now surounded"<<endl;
        cout<<"your men loose stats"<<endl;
        faction1attack -=50;
        faction1hp -= 50;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
    }
  }
  else if(StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator)==3){
    cout<<"the "<< FactionName2 << " are holding position what will you do"<<endl;
    cout<<"(1)chage foward. if your enemy wont come to you, you go to them"<<endl;
    cout<<"(2)tell your archers to hide on the flanks further up than your army and send in a platoon of men to attack and try to draw your enemy into a trap"<<endl;
    cout<<"(3)approach slowly keeping your gard up"<<endl;
    cin>> ArmyMove;
    if(ArmyMove ==1){
        cout<<"you charge foward meeting your enemy head on"<<endl;
        if(trapsuccess(RandomGenerator)<0.4){
            cout<<"the enemy were hoping you would do this and have a trap in place. You take archer fire from each side"<<endl;
            cout<<"your men loose stats"<<endl;
            faction1hp -= 60;
            faction1attack -= 60;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
           BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
        else if(trapsuccess(RandomGenerator)>0.4){
            cout<<"you were lucky the enemy had no plan in place"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
    }
    else if(ArmyMove == 2){
        if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) >=0.41){
            cout<<"your trap was a success your men get stat boosts"<<endl;
            faction1hp += 50;
            faction1attack +=50;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
        else if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) <= 0.4){
            cout<<"your trap failed the enemy realised what you where doing and countered. stats lost "<<endl;
            faction2hp += 20;
            faction2attack += 40;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
    } 
    else if(ArmyMove == 3){
        if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) >= 0.25)
            cout<<"your men approach causiosly and spot a trap being set so you counter. stat boost"<<endl;
        faction1attack +=40;
        faction1hp += 40;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
    }
    else if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) < 0.25){
        cout<<"your men are causious but dont detect the trap. stats lost"<<endl;
        faction2attack +=40;
        faction2hp += 40;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
        BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
    }
  }
  else if(faction2 == 1) {
    if(StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator) == 3){
        cout<<"the Romans are forming the Testudo formation"<<endl;
        cout<<"what will you do"<<endl;
        cout<<"(1) barrage them with arrows they dont stand a chance"<<endl;
        cout<<"(2) charge tell all your men to charge them"<<endl;
        cout<<"(3) fire arrows and do a cavelry charge"<<endl;
        cin>>ArmyMove;
        if(ArmyMove = 1){
            if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) >= 0.95){
                cout<<"you got lucky the Testudo formation was not set properly"<<endl;
                cout<<"you cut them down with your arrows. stat boost"<<endl;
                faction1attack += 60;
                faction1hp +=80;
                cout<<" "<<endl;
                cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
                cout<<" "<<endl;
                BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
            }
        }
        else if(ArmyMove == 2){
            cout<<"you charge your enemy head on"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
        else if(ArmyMove == 3){
            cout<<"good job the legions not at fighting cavelry and skirmishers seperatly"<<endl;
            cout<<"but not together. stat boost"<<endl;
            faction1attack += 50;
            faction1hp += 50;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
    }
    else if(StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator) == 4){
        cout<<"your enemy has chosen the battle field carefully"<<endl;
        cout<<"the ground is flat and perfect for the enemy chariots"<<endl;
        cout<<"what will you do"<<endl;
        cout<<"(1) who cares they dont stand a chance against me"<<endl;
        cout<<"(2) shift your cavelry to more ruff ground and hope they follow"<<endl;
        cout<<"(3) bring spearmen to the front so they can take on the chariots"<<endl;
        cin>>ArmyMove;
        if(ArmyMove == 1){
            cout<<"the battle ground sutes the enemy they get stat boost"<<endl;
            faction2attack +=60;
            faction2hp +=60;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
        }
        else if(ArmyMove == 2){
            if(yourmove(RandomGenerator)>= 0.4){
                cout<<"your tactics work and your enemy follow you off to ruffer terrain"<<endl;
                cout<<"losing their battle advantage and gaining advantage for yourself"<<endl;
                faction1hp += 60;
                faction1attack += 60;
                cout<<" "<<endl;
                cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
                cout<<" "<<endl;
                BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
            }else
            if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) < 0.4){
                cout<<"your plan fails and the enemy sees what you are doing"<<endl;
                cout<<"he drives your army back to their chosen battlefield"<<endl;
                cout<<"stats lost"<<endl;
                faction1hp -=30;
                faction1attack -=30;
                cout<<" "<<endl;
                cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
                cout<<" "<<endl;
                BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
            }
        }
        else if(ArmyMove == 3){
            if(yourmove(RandomGenerator) >= 90){
                cout<<"you got lucky the enemy chariots were untrained and your spearmen provail"<<endl;
                cout<<"stats increase"<<endl;
                faction1attack += 30;
                faction1hp += 30;
                cout<<" "<<endl;
                cout<<"<battle sounds>"<<endl;
                cout<<" "<<endl;
                BattleSim(faction2hp, faction1hp, faction1attack, faction2attack, faction1size, faction2size, orghpfaction1, orghpfaction2);
            }
        }
    }
  }


  if(faction1size <= 0){
    cout<<FactionName2 << " are victorious"<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<endl;

  }
  else if(faction2size <=0){
    cout<<FactionName1 << " are victorious"<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<endl;
  }


  EndStatment(GeneralName, FactionName1, FactionName2, orgfaction1size, faction1size, orgfaction2size, faction2size);


  return 0;
}


int AmountOfYourMen(string FactionName1)
{
  //amount of your men
  int faction1size;

  cout<<"how many "<< FactionName1 <<":";
  cin>>faction1size;

  return faction1size;
}

int AmountOfEnemyMen(string FactionName2)
{
  //amount of enemy men
  int faction2size;

  cout<<"how many "<< FactionName2 <<":";
  cin>>faction2size;

  return faction2size;
}

int EndStatment(string GeneralName, string FactionName1, string FactionName2, int orgfaction1size, int faction1size, int orgfaction2size, int faction2size)
{
  cout<<" "<<endl;
  cout<<FactionName1<< " casulties:"<< orgfaction1size - faction1size<<endl;
  cout<<FactionName1<<" men remaining:"<< faction1size<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;
  cout<<FactionName2<< " casulties:"<< orgfaction2size - faction2size<<endl;
  cout<<FactionName2<<" men remaining:"<< faction2size<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;

  if(faction1size <= 0){
    cout<<"General "<< GeneralName <<" you have been defeated and discraced"<<endl;
    cout<<"you should must regain your honor by playing again and wining"<<endl;
  }
  else if(faction2size<=0){
    cout<<"General "<< GeneralName << " you were VICTORIOUS"<<endl;
    cout<<"continue your military superiority by playing again"<<endl;
  }
}

void BattleSim(int &faction2hp, int &faction1hp, int &faction1attack, int &faction2attack, int &faction1size, int &faction2size, int &orghpfaction1, int &orghpfaction2)
{
  uniform_real_distribution<float> AttackRoll(0.0,1);
  mt19937 RandomBattle(time(NULL));

  do {
    if(AttackRoll(RandomBattle) >= 0.5){
        faction2hp -= faction1attack;
        if(faction2hp <= 0){
            faction2size -=1;
            faction2hp = orghpfaction2;
        }
    }
    if(AttackRoll(RandomBattle) >= 0.5){
        faction1hp -= faction2attack;
        if(faction1hp <= 0){
            faction1size -=1;
            faction1hp = orghpfaction1;
        }
    }
  }while(faction1size >= 1 && faction2size >=1);
}
```

Comment: "doesnt seem to work sometimes" is not an error description, your code example is too long and does not compile because `EndStatment` does not return anything, and it's full of `cout` output most likely completely irrelevant to the problem. Why should `"continue your military superiority by playing again"` have anything to do with random numbers? You are not supposed to post your full code here, only the parts which exhibit the problem (but those must be complete and compilable, unless your problem is with compilation itself).

Comment: In the future, please describe the input sequence and the symptoms so that everybody can understand what's going wrong, and try on his own.  But fortunatly for this question, the problem was obvious enough to pop in the eye just by looking at your code ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be the way you use your `StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator)` :  you have to understand that **every time you call it, it will return you another number**.

**The problem:**

```
mt19937 RandomGenerator(time(NULL));     // ok !  You have a seeded random generator
uniform_int_distribution<int> StratergyRoll(1, 4);   // and you set the bounds
...
if(StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator) == 1) {  // Suppose result is 3
    ...
}
else if(StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator) == 2) {  // Suppose result is 1 :OUCH !!! 
    ...
}
...
```

So instead of getting one random number and reacting uppon its value, you are calculating between 1 and 4 random numbers.  So with a litle bit of misluck, your branch might not be as you exepect, and no action will be performed in a round !

**The solution:**

Use a variable to store the roll and analyse it:

```
...
int currentRoll = StratergyRoll(RandomGenerator);  // Store it
if( currentRoll  == 1) {  // Suppose result is 3
    ...
}
else if(currentRoll == 2) {  // Now it wont change and you're sure one of the branch will fire! 
    ...
}
...
```

**Remarks:**

**Important:** you have a similar problem in your way of using `yourmove` and `trapsuccess`. You need to solve this in the same way.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** you have a couple of statements `if (yourmove...)` that are not follwed by `{` but where the indentation of the subsequent lines suggest that they should belong to the same block (I've noted it while edditing your  indentation).  Thist affects strategyRoll which are 3 or more.

By the way,  instead of using a long chain of `if/else` you could consider using a `switch` statement here.

The function `EndStatment()` should return an `int` as promised by its declaration.  Or if you do never expect a return (which seems the case here) simply make it a `void` function.